# How to flock() an image?

Tags: php, flock

I am looking to flock() an image.

Currently I am using the following

```
$img = ImageCreateFromPng($img_path);
flock($img,LOCK_EX);
```

It seems that the GD library's file handle is not valid with flock. How can I access the image and flock the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `flock` only works on file handles (or [stream wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.streamwrapper.php) if they support locking).  So, if you want to lock an image when you read it, you'd need to open it twice:

```
$f = fopen($imgPath, 'r');
if (!$f) {
    //Handle error (file does not exist perhaps, or no permissions?)
}
if (flock($f, LOCK_EX)) {
    $img = imagecreatefrompng($imgPath);
    //...  Do your stuff here

    flock($f, LOCK_UN);
}
fclose($f);
```

Comment: hmmm, IF the image is flock'd then I get an error from imagecreatefrompng - saying that it is not a valid png. To test it just before I called imagecreatefrompng I called flock($f, LOCK_UN) and the code worked again.

Comment: I am using it on Windows at the moment. But this is only for testing.... it will be live on a linux server.

Comment: That's probrably why.  Windows has internal locking that prevents opening a file for write while another processes has it open.  It should work fine on Linux, for what it's worth (And not have the memory overhead of reading the file in a string in PHP)...

Answer (score 1):

$img in your example is not a file handle, it is a handle to a GD image resource in memory.

You can use imagecreatefromstring to load an image like this:

```
$file=fopen($fileName,"r+b");
flock($file,LOCK_EX);
$imageBinary=stream_get_contents($file);
$img=imagecreatefromstring($imageBinary);
unset($imageBinary); // we don't need this anymore - it saves a lot of memory
```

If you want to save a modified version of the image to the open stream you have to use [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php):

```
ob_start();
imagepng($img);
$imageBinary=ob_get_clean();

ftruncate($file,0);
fseek($file,0);
fwrite($file,$imageBinary);
unset($imageBinary);
flock($file,LOCK_UN);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: This looks like a good workaround to the problem of imagecreatefrompng not working on flocked files.

Comment: I get an error for a parameter missing for ftruncate... I looked it up seems to be the size that you wish to truncate the file by

Comment: I haven't tested it so you may also have to fseek($file,0) after the trucating.

Comment: I tried truncating it to 0... it generated a file twice the size of the original... I'll try fseek

Comment: Hmmm.. I just benchmarked it. This takes 600ms... imagecreatefrompng,imagepng ... takes 0.12ms. I am not sure its a viable option :S Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

`flock` only works with file pointers and `ImageCreateFromPng` only works with filenames. Try making two different calls:

```
$fp = fopen($img_path, 'r');
flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
$img = ImageCreateFromPng($img_path);
```

`flock` is cooperative, so it only works if everybody uses it. As long as `ImageCreateFromPng` doesn't use `flock`, the code above should work.

Comment: hmmm, If the image is flock'd then I get an error from imagecreatefrompng - saying that it is not a valid png. To test it just before I called imagecreatefrompng I called flock($fp, LOCK_UN) and the code worked again.

Comment: That's too bad. Maybe try locking the file and copying it to a temporary file. Then, operate on the temporary file while the main file is locked.

Comment: Thanks, ircmaxell assures me that it will work on linux... so i'll be using this method after all.